# how do I calculate the average of two datetime objects

Tags: python

I have a list containing datetime objects and want to calculate the average of two times from the list when a certain condition is met and insert it into the list.

```
 temp =datetime.fromtimestamp(offsetMat[i][j].timestamp()+offsetMat[i][j+1].timestamp()/2)
 offsetMat[i].insert(j,temp)
```

I tried this code but the result i get from the calculation doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tty this and check if it works:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Example datetime objects
dt1 = datetime(2023, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0)
dt2 = datetime(2023, 5, 3, 12, 0, 0)

# Calculate the average datetime
total_seconds = (dt2 - dt1).total_seconds()
average_seconds = total_seconds / 2
average_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(dt1.timestamp() + average_seconds)

# Print the result
print(average_datetime)
```